# Can't associate temp view with database in spark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a temp view using spark, from a csv file.

To reproduce my production scenario, I need to test my script locally, however in production I'm using Glue Jobs (AWS) where there are databases and tables.

In the code below, I'm creating a database in my spark session and using it, after that, I create a temp view.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("pulsar_data").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('csv')\
                       .options(infer_schema=True)\
                       .options(header=True)\
                       .load('pulsar_stars.csv')

spark.sql('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MYDB')
spark.sql('USE MYDB')

df.createOrReplaceTempView('MYDB.TB_PULSAR_STARS')

spark.catalog.listTables()
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM MYDB.TB_PULSAR_STARS').show()
```

However, when I try to select db.table, Spark can't find the relation between my temp view and my database and throws following error:

```
*** pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: MYDB.TB_PULSAR_STARS; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [MYDB, TB_PULSAR_STARS], [], false
```

Debugging my code with pdb, I have listed my spark session catalog, where I find that my table is in fact associated:

```
(Pdb) spark.catalog.listTables()
[Table(name='tb_pulsar_stars', database='MYDB', description=None, tableType='TEMPORARY', isTemporary=True)]
```

How can I make this relationship work?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary view name associated to a DataFrame can only be one segment. This is explicitly checked [here in Spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2440b6b731758308d0db88c10edb5b9a71d81c92/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L3806-L3811). I would expect your code to throw `AnalysisException: CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW or the corresponding Dataset APIs only accept single-part view names, but got: MYDB.TB_PULSAR_STARS` - not sure why in your case it's a bit different.

Anyway, use:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('TB_PULSAR_STARS')
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM TB_PULSAR_STARS').show()
```

And if you need to actually write this data to a table, create it using:

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE MYDB.TB_PULSAR_STARS AS SELECT * FROM TB_PULSAR_STARS")
```

Comment: I tried the "create as select" solution, but it requires hive support, and I don't have it locally. Actually, my question is about why the relation between database and tempview is shown when I list tables in spark catalog, if it doesn't work when I execute spark sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue - see below.

I'having the same issue using both

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('TB_PULSAR_STARS')
```

or the deprecated version

```
df.registerTempTable('TB_PULSAR_STARS')
```

and later on referring to this temporary table via:

```
df2 = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT * FROM TB_PULSAR_STARS
""")
```

resulting in this error message

```
AnalysisException: Table or view not found: TB_PULSAR_STARS; line 19 pos 12;
```

What is really odd is, that the code runs perfectly in AWS Glue during an interactive session, but does not during a Job Run.

Update: I managed to solve this using either global temporary views:

```
df.createGlobalTempView('TB_PULSAR_STARS')
df2 = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT * FROM global_temp.TB_PULSAR_STARS
""")
```

or temp views: As I finally found out, creating temp views from a dataframe only work in Job Runs with dynamic frames combined with toDF(). So an example would be:

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame
.from_catalog(database ="mydatabase", table_name = "mytable", push_down_predicate=mypredicate)
.toDF()

df.createOrReplaceTempView('TB_PULSAR_STARS')
df2 = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT * FROM TB_PULSAR_STARS
""")
```